# Cloud functions for Firebase: Update/Set using admin sdk which returns a promise

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

In Cloud Functions for Firebase, for example:

```
exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original')
    .onWrite(event => {
    //how to write data at another node and return promise?
    return admin.database().ref(`/abc/1234`).update({a:1}); //is this the correct way? 

})
```

In https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started, it says

```
// You must return a Promise when performing asynchronous tasks inside a Functions such as
      // writing to the Firebase Realtime Database.
      // Setting an "uppercase" sibling in the Realtime Database returns a Promise.
```

but in https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data, the apis are using callback. May I know how to set/update data inside firebase functions correctly? The code will work but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly or if it's the recommended way. Thanks.

Comment: The Firebase SDKs support both promises and callbacks. See [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html) for more detail. In short -- what you wrote above should work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every write operation in the Firebase Database SDK returns a promise, so that you can chain it or return it to the Google Cloud Functions environment. See the blog post Michael mentioned: [Keeping our Promises (and Callbacks)](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html).

So these two code snippets will do the same. With callbacks:

```
var ref = admin.database().ref(`/abc/1234`);
ref.update({a:1}, function(error) {
  if (!error) {
    console.log("Write completed")
  }
  else {
    console.error("Write failed: "+error)
  }
});
```

With promises:

```
var ref = admin.database().ref(`/abc/1234`);
ref.update({a:1}).then(function() {
  console.log("Write completed")
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.error("Write failed: "+error)
});
```